# Discord.py error AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'

Tags: discord.py

why it no work
`

```
#Importing stuff
import discord
import os
import random
from discord.ext import commands

#Variables
command_prefix = '!'
intents = discord.Intents.all()
token = 'MTAzOTA3ODMyODcxMzM1NTMwNA.GMKlpL.gLzQ9H6UCaAE7PNeb0Nv-I2cb-e8p-NgZZJydY'


#Client Setup
bot = discord.Client(command_prefix=command_prefix, intents=intents)


#On ready function (startup)
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Online')
    #Status Setup
    activity = discord.Game(name="Put Status Here", type=3)
    await bot.change_presence(activity=activity)


@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send('baller')


#Run
bot.run(token)
```

`

i tried a bunch of other stuff but it no worky pls help me

Error:
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'

Comment: Please don't display your token publicly :)

Comment: i reset is after dont worry